# -3 reputation instead of -2 after question deletion.

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions

One of my question was deleted by mods, after I flagged it as unconstructive, (it was a a perfect duplicate)

```
-3   1 hour ago removed Why can't I use somefunction()[0] in PHP?
```

there was no up/down votes, and an accepter answer (1 line, pointing to docs and duplicate question)

Why -3 and not -2 then?
Is this a compensation for the person that answered?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11495253) (10K+ only), you were given 1 upvote, and 1 downvote. You never accepted an answer. That means you gained 3 points total (+5 for an upvote, -2 for a downvote).

When the question was deleted, you thus lost the 3 reputation points again.